# split, rearrange, and join a string

Tags: ruby, regex

If I have a string such as `string = "08/01/2012"`

How can I return "2012-08-01" in Ruby in one line?

e.g. take the set of digits after the last "/", insert them at the beginning, then replace the "/"s with "-"s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with dates, I'd go through the `Date` library (you have to `require 'date'` for some of the features) because it's the most flexible and stable approach:

```
Date.strptime(string, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#=> "2012-08-01"
```

As you can see both `strptime` ("string parse time") and `strftime` ("string format time") take format strings that exactly describe what they are doing.

If you don't want to go through `Date`, you can use `gsub` like this:

```
string.gsub(%r{(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)}, '\3-\1-\2')
#=> "2012-08-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m, d, y = string.split("/")
"#{y}-#{m}-#{d}"
```

or

```
string.split("/").rotate(-1).join("-")
```

Comment: @aperture: Yes, it can be done in one line. Just remove the line breaks: `m, d, y = string.split("/"); "#{y}-#{m}-#{d}"`. Not sure why you'd want to do that, though.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think the OP wanted to do it in a chain.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I needed to match two different date formats within a view using data attributes. I don't know of any other way to use ruby inside a view to return a string without it being a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Kohl answer is correct

just another answer

```
Date.parse(string).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
month, day, year = string.split('/').map(&:to_i)
rearranged = sprintf "%04d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day
```

It does a little extra work (in that it does `to_i` on each element), but it could come in handy later.

Answer (score 0):

I find it more simple:

```
'30/10/2016'.split('/').reverse().join('-')
```